# Connections between loops (algebraic structure) and graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, latin-square

I would like to know whether there are known constructions which provide a bijection between loops (isomorphism classes) and (possibly directed) graphs. Any reference to a useful paper in this direction will be appreciated.

Searching combinations of words "graphs, loops, representation, bijection" the hits contain too many irrelevant links, so I get stacked. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The question was reposted also on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/184798/connections-between-loops-algebraic-structure-and-graphs

Answer (score 1):

I have no clean bijection as the one you are looking for.
But there is a classical link between latin squares of order $n$ and distance-regular graphs on $n^2$ vertices and diameter 2.

See

- Relevant keywords : partial geometries, strong regular graphs
- See articles and books by H. Van Lint, Peter Cameron.
- Chris Godsil and Gordon Royle "Algebraic Graph Theory", GTM 207, Chapter 10.

But of course, this is not the only way to consider graphs associated with loops, latin squares, orthogonal sets, ...

The literature about finite geometries, projective planes, generalized quadrangles is very instructive in this respect.

Comment: Thank you. I have already known that from a Latin square I can construct an SRG. But I do not know,  whether _different_ (in the sense of isomorphism or isotopism or up to conjugation) Latin squares give non-isomorphic SRGs, or not. So I am looking for any source in this direction. I can imagine that this is a quite hard task.